# C++ Making a container-like class

Tags: c++, templates, containers

I'm trying to make a class that's supposed to define the behavior of a graph search algorithm.

The class receives a generic container as a template argument and acts based on the container

```
template <typename N, typename E, class Container>
class Frontier {
    private:
        Container frontier;

    public:
        bool isEmpty() { return this.frontier.empty(); }

        typename Graph<N, E>::const_iterator pop() { return this.frontier.pop(); }

        bool push(typename Graph<N, E>::const_iterator it) { return this.frontier.push(it); }
};
```

but when i try to compile i get

```
request for member ‘frontier’ in ‘this’, which is of non-class type
```

I know this can be done because stl containers are implemented as such

```
template<class T, Class C = deque<T> > class std::stack;
```

I noticed the capital C in Class so I tried using Class in the implementation but I got "Class was not defined" from the compiler. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed the end of the error message, which would tell you that `this` is a pointer, and ask you if you meant to use `->` instead of `.`. That should resolve the error.

Note that `class` and `typename` are equivalent in the template argument list. No big deal, but consistency is nice. (Note that `Class` is not valid as a keyword. Not sure where you got that from...)

```
template <typename N, typename E, typename Container>
class Frontier {
    private:
        Container frontier;

    public:
        bool isEmpty() { return this->frontier.empty(); }

        typename Graph<N, E>::const_iterator pop() { return this->frontier.pop(); }

        bool push(typename Graph<N, E>::const_iterator it) { return this->frontier.push(it); }
};
```

Comment: Can't beleive i missed that. I ought to update that pesky compiler so it'll display error messages correctly (that's actually the entire error message and my gcc version is really old.)